# Why is Cygwin ftp hanging on connect?

Tags: ftp, cygwin

I'm trying to use the Cygwin ftp client in Windows 7 but it just hangs on connect:

```
$ ftp -d ftp.redhat.com
User (ftp.redhat.com:(none)): anonymous
---> USER anonymous
Password:
```

Windows ftp from a command prompt connects without any issue:

```
C:\> ftp ftp.redhat.com
Connected to ftp.redhat.com.
220 Red Hat FTP server ready. All transfers are logged. <FTP> [no EPSV]
User (ftp.redhat.com:(none)): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the appearance is misleading.
Could it be that there *is no* default FTP support in Cygwin ?

```
$ which ftp
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ftp
```

whereas the usual directory for Cygwin executables has no such file:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/ftp*
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/ftp*: No such file or directory
```

That means that it's actually the Windows7 FTP client that is being launched from the Cygwin prompt, which is currently not supported. In the link provided by [Tim Supinie](https://superuser.com/users/291085/tim-supinie), compatibility problems are mentioned for the blanking that needs to happen when the user enters his password.

My solution has been to look for a Cygwin variant of FTP, but Cygwin's `setup.exe` is remarkably clumsy at this point. I was only being offered some fancier FTP clients. The solution was also provided in that link. [Kevin Panko](https://superuser.com/users/3680/kevin-panko), it literally instructs to download the `inetutils` package in Cygwin, which contains popular networking clients. By entering that word in Cygwin's `setup.exe`, I ended up with the true native FTP client under Cygwin, as proven by:

```
$ which ftp
/usr/bin/ftp
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find an answer?  I ran into this problem recently, and [this link](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-08/msg00645.html) seems to indicate that Cygwin cannot run FTP natively.  One needs to download a separate Cygwin FTP client or just use the native Windows command line FTP client.  As for the reason why Cygwin fails, the link goes into a little bit of detail.

Comment: Please summarize what the link says, in your answer.  If the link goes down, then your answer will not be helpful in the future.